# Discord.js Chatbot

Tags: mongoose, discord.js

Please help me. This my my code below regarding chatbot for discord.js

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const {ChannelType} = require("discord.js");

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    const chatbots = require("./All-Commands-Schemas/ChatbotSchema")
    chatbots.findOne({ guild: message.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
        if (!data) return;
        if (err) throw err
        const channell = data.channel;
        if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === ChannelType.DM) return;

        if (message.channel.id === channell) {
            message.channel.sendTyping();
            await fetch(`http://api.brainshop.ai/get?bid=164279&key=rhBjCAZC83ztKzYO&uid=${message.author.id}&msg=${message.content}`)
                .then(cnt => cnt.json())
                .then(data => {
                    message.channel.send(data.cnt);
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    message.channel.send("Couldn't fetch response!");
                })
        }
    })
})
```

Chatbot Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const chatbots = new mongoose.Schema({
    guild: String,
    channel: String,
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("chatbots", chatbots);
```

The problem is that the chatbot does not reply back or show errors in the console log. i have tried everything.

"node-fetch": "^3.3.0",
"discord.js": "^14.6.0",
"mongoose": "^6.7.0"

Comment: Did you enable the message content intent and specify it when creating your client?

Answer (score 0):

**Replace:**

```js
const channell = data.channel;
```

**With:**

```js
const channell = client.channels.cache.get(data.channel);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you cannot directly use

```js
const channell = data.channel
```

To get a channel dynamically you have to fetch it from the cache by using the

```js
channels.cache.get()
```

So, you shall replace

```js
const channell = data.channel
```

With

```js
const channell = client.channels.cache.get(data.channel)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this**

```
 .then(data => {
                message.channel.send(data.cnt);
            })
```

**With this**

```
  .then(Data => {
 message.channel.send(Data.cnt);
})
```

Cause you are fetching data from mongo and with the API as well. So, both parameters can't be same.

As for the channel its all good. As, you are comparing Ids so no need to cache fetch the channel.